# Promisify cluster worker events on message

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, es6-promise

I am trying to find a way to "promisify" event callbacks on workers, so that the master can:

1. wait for all workers to finish CPU intensive tasks,
2. then do some calculation based on the results returned.

I came up with the following code and this works fine, however I am not confident with the approach I am taking.

Function to creaet a promise that wraps the message event on a worker:

```js
 _waitAsync(worker) {
    // using bluebird for Promise
    return Promise.promisify((callback) => {
      worker.on('message', callback.bind(undefined, undefined));
    })();
  }
```

Master calls as below:

```js
doCPUIntensiveTaskAsync(){
    const promises = [];
    let k = 0;
    for (var wid in cluster.workers) {
      promises.push(this._waitAsync(cluster.workers[wid]).bind(this));
      cluster.workers[wid].send(messages[k++]);
    }
    return Promise.all(promises).then(calulcate);
}
```

What are the recommended / better ways to take advantage of multi-core environment (ie. offload CPU intensive tasks to different thread/process) in Node.js?

Comment: If `worker` can send more than one `message` through its lifetime, then you are going to be orphaning event handlers and they will accumulate.  The orphaned event handlers will just be trying to resolve an already resolved promise which does nothing, but it's not a good practice as the event handlers can build up indefinitely and it keeps your promise from being garbage collected.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, and yes, my workers will be receiving more than one messages in their lifetime. If that's the case, do you think calling `worker.removeAllListeners('message')` each time before assigning a new event listener in `_waitAsync` would improve the code?

Comment: I don't, in general, like that architecture.  Promises don't mesh well with event listeners - there's just an impedance mismatch between a one-shot promise device and a repeat event listener.  I'd have to understand more of your overall code to get an idea what the best way to do it might be.

Answer (score 0):

1. start worker per each 'CPU intensive task', then let them exit. Don not reuse workers, restart them for next task.
2. Easy way to promisify worker exit:

   ```
   import * as Q from 'q';

   let worker = cluster.fork();
   let workerExit = Q.denodeify(w.on.bind(w, 'exit'));
   await workerExit();// here can be workerExit().then ... instead of await

   console.log('child exited');
   ```

Comment: Is there a similar approach using Bluebird JS?